# Smart Contract Close Function

Tags: eosio.token

cleos push action eosio.token close '["bob","TIK"]' -p alice@active

I'm calling close function of eosio.token smart contract using above command on local node.[image]

Answer (score 1):

`eosio::symbol` consists of `decimals,symbol_code` like `4,EOS`.

Comment: Thanks now I used cleos push action eosio.token close ‘[“bob”,”0,TIK”]’ -p account@active